# How to avoid stuttering of circle avatar inside animated list Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to avoid stuttering inside circle avatar image when using AnimatedList Widget?

The stuttering can be seen on the gif below

[image]

and my current implementation of animated list is

```
    Widget _buildSearchResults() {
    return AnimatedList(
                key: _searchResultListKey,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                initialItemCount: _searchResults.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                  return _buildSearchResultItem(
                      context, index, _searchResults[index], animation);
                },
              ),
    }

    Widget _buildSearchResultItem(
      BuildContext context, int index, User user, Animation<double> animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      axis: Axis.vertical,
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.h),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: user.imageURL,
              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: imageProvider,
              ),
              placeholder: (context, url) => BulbiLoading(),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 35.w),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    user.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: BulbiColors.primary,
                      fontSize: 38.ssp,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15.h),
                  Text(
                    "@${user.username}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                      fontSize: 35.ssp,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20.w),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                onSurface: BulbiColors.secondary,
                primary: BulbiColors.secondary,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _invitedUsers.add(user);
                  _invitedUserListKey.currentState.insertItem(
                    _invitedUsers.length - 1,
                    duration: _transitionDuration,
                  );
                  final removedUser = _searchResults.removeAt(index);
                  _searchResultListKey.currentState.removeItem(
                    index,
                    (context, animation) => _buildSearchResultItem(
                        context, index, removedUser, animation),
                    duration: _transitionDuration,
                  );
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                "Invite",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: BulbiColors.secondary,
                  fontSize: 39.ssp,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );}
```

If I remove the circle avatar image, it won't have the same problem as shown above, but I can't do that because I need the circle avatar to make the UI clearer for the user

Is there anyone who has the same problem as me?

Thank you